# Using mongodb driver how to do not in $regex query

Tags: regex, mongodb

From searching the internet i am not sure if this is possible so i figured i would ask you smart people.

I am trying to allow a admin users of a site free range to do more advanced search queries. The db is mongo. Whatever is inputed into the search input gets put into a `{"$regex": "{user input}"}`.

I know i can use `$not` operator, but i am wondering if a NOT could be applied in the $regex field. This would save me from having to parse the input and fill in the `$not` and just let the `$regex` handle it.

This would only be available to admins who knew how to put the regex into the search input so i don't need to worry about complexity for simple users.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:
Also, i figured out later what i was really meaning with $not was $ne. Something where a user could type `"someFieldName" $ne "someId"` which would be put in the $regex query to mongo and get results for all documents where `someFieldName` doesn't have `someId'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regex has no `$not`-like operators.

If you want to return some line/entry that doesn't contain a query string, you can use

`"^(?:(?!" + $query_string + ").)*$"`

Here is a verbal description of [`^(?:(?!query).)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/iX3lP3/1) regex that will match a line not containing the word "query":

[image]

To [enforce PCRE flavor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#syntax-restrictions), you should use *$regex* operator with the pattern as a string (replace *[your_query_string]* with the actual query):

```
{ $regex: '^(?:(?![your_query_string]).)*$' }
```

Comment: Thanks for response, i appreciate it! I will mark the answer but I am not a pro with regex and was hoping you could explain the details of the regex? And just to make sure, what you put would go in {"$regex": "{your line}"} for the mongo query? I also understand more from research and added a "EDIT" to the question if you have time to look. Thanks.

Comment: @j_walker_dev: I added a sample query and its explanation.